# SWITCH returns TRUE when comparing letters to numbers. WHY?

Tags: php, switch-statement

Short question: **WHY?!?**

The below class returns *ALL ALLRIGHT* when calling:`Status::validate('ab')`

```
class Status
{
    const FRESH = 0;
    const PENDING = 25;
    const CANCELLED = 50;

    public static function validate($status)
    {
        switch ($status) {
            case self::FRESH:
            case self::PENDING:
            case self::CANCELLED:
                echo 'ALL ALLRIGHT';
            default:
                echo 'ERROR!';
        }
        die;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it is returning that because it is the last of the case statements or it is actually hitting 50 as value. What happens when you swap cancelled and pending lines and leave allright where it is ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's because your `$status` is being casted to int.

```
$value = 'abc';
$other_value = '21abc';

echo (int)$value;
echo '<br>';
echo (int)$other_value;
```

Will return:

```
0
21
```

And that would cause it to think that `ab` value is equal to `Status::FRESH`

I'm not sure though if `switch` statement does this type of typecasting.

## Edit

And I think I was right. More info here [PHP Manual - switch](http://php.net/manual/pl/control-structures.switch.php#82351).
Reference on typecasting strings to integers here [PHP Manual - Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

Comment: It seems like if there is a case that involves matching an `int` that it will cast the conditional value to `int` for all the comparisons in the switch, even if there are string comparisons in the switch. At least that's what testing showed me. `0 == (int)'ab'` (which you showed using 'abc')